# Is it possible to log a program's network activity in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, logging

Does anyone know of a program or way to log all network activity to a specific program on one's computer (program and/or service)?

I know I can see this "live" in Resource Monitor, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of a program or way to track and log all network activity to/from a specific process and/or service.

I'm finding a lot of "live"-type monitors, like Windows Resource Monitor, but nothing that can log.

Comment: You might be looking for [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will do this

You will need to set up a filter - wireshark has some premade ones, or you can set your own using a string - this can be a protocol name or port

[image]

Or you can log everything and filter later

[image]